# Dropdown Navigation CSS Issue

Tags: php, html, css, navigation, dropdown

new to this board, please bear with me.

I've seen a lot of similar threads to my issue but I still can't find a solution so I decided to see if I could get some help here.

The majority of the code was done by someone else -- I'm not a coder / developer by any means so I'm basically doing damage control with my limited knowledge. If you look at the CSS you'll see that the guy did a sloppy job.

Here's a link to one of the pages: http://bumbu.com/recipes.php -- but the issue applies to the whole site. It is regarding the navigation, and is in the style.css (line 108-231) (possibly the header html as well)

Issues:

1. There are two dropdowns - one under 'the Blend' and one under 'Cocktails', when you mouse on the Blend dropdown and mouse away the dropdown glitchily appears on the left side of the screen and is overlapping somehow.
2. The whole navigation is positioned using a really stupid system of margin-lefts and padding on multiple classes and when I change one thing it messes up the other. You can see that the dropdown on Cocktails isn't positioned perfectly to the link and the yellow bar hover state.
3. There are also some really stupid breakpoints (around 1025px and 990px) that you'll see are also messing up the dropdowns to the point you cant even click the dropdown links. When I give new CSS to the breakpoint it messes up the desktop state and vice versa.

I've tried messing with all the different navigation and drop down CSS by trial and error and when I get one thing right something else messes up. Since the site looks good to me otherwise I don't really want to re do all the code for the nav from scratch. Any help would be useful. Thanks in advance!! If there's more info I can give that can help let me know.

Screenshot of the issue:

[image]
<sub>(source: [bumbu.com](http://bumbu.com/example.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Er.. This is not http://freelancer.com. Please read [ask] and How to create a [mcve].

Comment: You are not supposed to be rude. StackOverflow is a place, where you can get help **if you are stuck**, not code everything. And you need to provide a **[mcve]**.

Comment: Let me know if the answer works. I took time to analyse it and have spent some time. Give some respect for that at least!

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, I asked because I AM stuck. Maybe you misunderstood when I said I don't want to rewrite the navigation from scratch as me asking someone else to do it for me (I'm not). I was just hoping someone could point me in the right direction or which area in the CSS might be causing the dropdown issue.

Comment: Okay, kindly check out the answer and tell if it works.

Comment: Thanks again for your help -- I will try it out. sorry for flipping out, this is my first question so I felt a little offended that it was being made to sound that I'm asking for free labor, which was not my intent.

Comment: Did it work? Any good thing happened?

Comment: http://bumbu.com/example.jpg    I've uploaded a screenshot of what I mean, since I can't attach one at the moment. Your advice does fix the alignment of the dropdown but then this issue appears. For some reason the styling of the two dropdowns are different instead of just one. Let me know if that is confusing. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the developer has used margins for alignment, which is a worst practice. But this fixes it:

```
.sub-nav2 {
  transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: -108px; /* Change this here. */
  margin-top: 90px;
}
```

You may need to do some tweaking with the `108px`. What I see is:

[image]

**Solution for Skipping**

```
/* Line #185 */
nav ul ul {
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-top: 85px;
}
/* Line #195 */
.sub-nav2 {
  margin-left: -108px;
  margin-top: 85px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying to post a screenshot to show what I mean since it's a bit confusing to explain in writing. That does fix the alignment but then another issue appears, which you can see on the left side of the screen when you mouse away from 'The Blend' dropdown. If you mouse over on the farthest left side of the screen below the gradient you might see what I mean.

Comment: @solomonskee Let me know what's the screen size, the browser you are using, coz does the screenshot that I provided look good?

Comment: Your suggestion does fix the alignment on 'Cocktails' and looks good on my screen, but the issue in bumbu.com/example.jpg  then appears, for some reason when I don't fix the alignment the issue in the screenshot I attached is gone. So it's either one problem or the other if that makes sense.

Comment: @solomonskee Can you kindly draw a line or something that shows the issue? Sorry I still don't get it.

Comment: Sorry, I know it is confusing -- I've uploaded a screen capture video of what I mean. http://bumbu.com/example.m4v   If you look at the left side of the screen you will see the glitch that is happening. The alignment looks good when I use your CSS but the glitch doesnt appear on Cocktails if I keep it how it was (the glitch always appears on 'The Blend'

Comment: @solomonskee Awesome. Lemme have a look.

Comment: @solomonskee You mean, that place it goes off, right? I know how to fix.

Comment: Yes I believe so, the part that is appearing on the left side of the screen and overlapping. Thank you so much.

Comment: @solomonskee Now kindly add the above updated CSS at the end of `style.css` or replace at the lines.

Comment: @solomonskee You there?

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to be working, let me play with it for a few minutes, and make sure I'm doing it right, thank you for your help.

Comment: http://bumbu.com/css1.png I've attached a image of what happened when I replaced those lines with your suggestions, perhaps I did something wrong?